# Does a 100A outlet for a car charger need a dedicated disconnect?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am going to be installing a charger for a client for their Tesla. 
Do I need to ha e a separate shut off box for a double gang 100amp breaker for the charger?

Comment: You might [revise](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/156309/edit) to tell us where you are and why you're asking (code question, Tesla specs question...).

Comment: I'm in Colorado, west of Boulder. I'm asking due to needing to install a charger for a client

Comment: Running it about 35-40' total under ground from breaker box to a shed.

Comment: Is the 100A breaker within line-of-sight of the car?

Answer (score 2):

Receptacle plugs can serve as a means to disconnect an appliance.

If there is no receptacle, but is instead direct-wired, appliances rated over 300 volt-amperes require a disconnect.  If the breaker box is within sight and is 50 ft or less the breaker can serve as the disconnect.  If it is not within sight, then a means to lock the breaker in the off position can suffice as a disconnect.

Addendum: There is a small section in the code that talks about car charging disconnects.  As mentioned by another post, 2011 625.23 says greater than 60A or 150 volts to ground requires a disconnect --  That section was moved to 625.42 in the 2014, and to 625.43 in 2017.

That being said, 60A or less can use a receptacle plug as a disconnect if listed by the manufacture, and with residential 150V to ground is not an concern.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't see why it would since it is not like it's an air conditioner that might need to be serviced from outside the home.

EDIT:

From a search, 2011 NEC 625.23 says it will require a disconnect if it's greater than 60A.

Comment: The run I need to make is about 35-40' just for the electrical part. Plus buried @least 24".

Comment: Given such a short run, consider Rigid metal conduit, the type that requires pipe threading. Expensive, but only requires a 6" burial depth (12" under vehicle routes).

Comment: Got this from a search: 2011 NEC 625.23 Disconnecting Means. This article requires a lockable disconnect in a readily accessible location if the equipment is rated greater then 60 amps. Locking your feeder breaker would not satisfy this requirement unless a permanent locking device was added to your panel. I do not believe such a device is available for common home panels.

Comment: So I guess since it's 100A and not 60A, you should probably add a disconnect

Comment: @jassem abdal , there are lots of aftermarket permanent locking devices that meet the NEC requirement. I have several for square d on my desk. Qo1pl is the part number they are spendy at 8-9$ each, there are kits that can retrofit an entire panel so every breaker can be locked. The reason most folks don't see these is the big box stores usually won't stock them but electrical supply houses do.